# jquery accept httpRequest.attribute in special case uses after iframe refresh-free submission form

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax

i want javascript to accept httprequest attribute,and i know should be

```
var value = '${attrubuteName}'
```

my question is :
i want to use iframe to implement no refresh submit,like:

```
<s:form namespace="/forum" id="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target"> 
            <s:file name="upload"  id="upload_2"></s:file>
            <s:submit ></s:submit>
    </s:form>
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" ></iframe>
```

and jquery to implement submit,accept httpRequest.attribute.path,and alert path value like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $('input[id^="upload"]').change(function(){
      $("#form1").attr("action","tReplyAction_uploadFile");
      $("#form1").submit();
        var path = '${path}';
        alert(path);
</script> 
    });
```

and tReplyAction_uploadFile method is :

```
public void uploadFile() throws IOException{             
        String path = "d:/a/b";
        httpServletRequest.setAttribute("path", path);              
}
```

when complete this method,alert(""); how can i accept the path attribute in this case？
thanks.